# How to speed up video by more than 100x

Tags: time-lapse

I have a video editor that can speed up video (Shotcut) but it can only go to 50x. I have 90 minutes of video that I want to compress into 15 seconds (360x). How should I go about doing this? I know I can export it and then speed it up again, but that seems inefficient - is there some other software that can speed up video by a lot?

Comment: What platform are you using?  Different systems will support different software, if you can add more information we can help much more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a free one off option, I would recommend using ffmpeg.  Don't let commandline put you off, there's a ton of helpful stuff that will let you build a one off command to do this.  Here's a couple of links that will help.

https://superuser.com/a/1261681/653198

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video